# Does Google Analytics SDK 2.0 for iOS symbolicate crash reports?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

There is no mention of this on their website, [Google Analytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/)

I am talking about the automatic uncaught exception handling:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES; // Enable 
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory this would only be possible if either you don't strip symbols from your app binary, resulting in larger binary files (up to 30-50% bigger). Or if you upload the dSYM, which would allow you to get line numbers too.

Since you can't upload dSYM files, and the documentation doesn't seem you to require leaving the symbols in the app binary, they won't symbolicate crashes caused by uncaught exceptions.