# NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: < redacted> < redacted> < redacted> in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c

For my released app, I see this error in Google Analytics:

> NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: < redacted> < redacted>  redacted>
>   AppName AppName AppName AppName AppName < redacte ....

Futhermore, analytics says the error appears just in `iOS 6.0 version`. For `iOS 7.0`, there are no errors. The users say the application doesn't show anything. Just loading screen. No more.

Does somebody know this error? May be there is a typical solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is app crash log details. Google Analytics  try to decode crash log into user understandable. But It couldn't do this. that's why, this tag `< redacted>` appears. Usually this is called as `crash backtrace symbols`. If you provide correct `dSYM` file to google analytics account, then it may decode as expected.

**Note:** I don't know, but according [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580889/does-google-analytics-sdk-2-0-for-ios-symbolicate-crash-reports), there's no way to upload dSYM file to google analytics. So If you remove this line `[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;`, this will simply disappear temporarily.

Comment: I understand this.but there error can appear if application crashes at the very begin and shows just launching screen?